# How can I pipe the contents of two different files as arguments using xargs and cat?

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, cat, xargs

I have two different files, file1.txt and file2.txt and I need to pipe the content of both files (separately) as arg1 and arg2 to a program.

I can do one file with

```
cat file1.txt | xargs ./prog
```

But how can I pipe both files?

Thanks.

Comment: show some examples of the content of each file...

Comment: you may want to change your `./prog`, e.g add one option `-f`, with this option, the two args would be filenames. then you could just do `./prog -f file1 file2` and in your script, read the two files.

Comment: @Kent I can't change prog.

Comment: @shellter That doesn't pass them as separate arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use command substitution instead of `xargs`, like so:

```
./prog "$(<file1.txt)" "$(<file2.txt)"
```

If you must remain compatible with POSIX `sh`, use the following instead:

```
./prog "`cat file1.txt`" "`cat file2.txt`"
```

Note that if you have multiple words in each file and you want them to be treated a separate arguments, remove the `" "` quotes (but not the `$( )` or `` ` ` ``).